# How can I get a screen reader to stop treating an HTML5 game like a document?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, accessibility, wai-aria, game-development

I'm working on an HTML5 game that entirely takes place in a canvas element that takes up the full page. I'm using [NV Access](https://www.nvaccess.org/) to test how it works with screen readers. By using a hidden div with `role="alert"` that I update with JavaScript, I can get the screen reader to read text.

However, NV Access already has keyboard commands for pretty much every keyboard key, so when I try to control the game with WASD, or the arrow keys, or pretty much anything that isn't a game controller, it intercepts my key presses before the game can process them.

I've set `role="application"` on both the page's body and the canvas on separate tests and neither position seemed to change anything.

The only context where I could get NV Access to give control to the browser tab was by adding a hidden textbox to the page and focusing on that, which worked, but had the side-effect of having the screen reader read every key press, which led to moving the character always being accompanied by the sounds of "s. s. sssssssssss. d. d. dddddddddd."

This is essentially what the game page looks like:

```html
<body role="application">
    <div>
       <div id="screenRead" role="alert"></div>
       <canvas id="background"></canvas>
       <canvas id="foreground"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ideally all key presses (barring control actions like Alt+Tab, Ctrl+Tab, etc.) will be accepted by the browser tab itself instead of being caught by a screen reader. Since player controls are configurable, adding exceptions for a few keys won't work (and `aria-keyshortcuts` didn't work for this context, anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to set the `role=application` which is correct, you must also make the `canvas` or a `div` focusable (`tabindex=0`) and effectively focus it (using the `.focus()` method).

Doing so, the screen reader should switch to focus mode, in which most keys are passed to your script.

If this isn't the case, press <kbd>insert+space</kbd> (NVDA) or <kbd>insert+Z</kbd> (Jaws). Ideally you should give this instruction to the player, of course.
Depending on settings, the switch between focus and browse mode may be manual only.

Be prepared to be unable to completely handle certain combinations like <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+F4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+Left/Right</kbd>, some <kbd>Alt+letter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+letter</kbd>.
Even though they may be caught by your script, their default behavior might not be cancelled by calling `event.preventDefault()` in certain browsers and OS.
<kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> is never caught on windows, for example. That's fortunate, otherwise you could completely prevent the user from exiting your page.

Comment: Putting `tabindex=0` on the div and focusing on it worked, thank you!